# bind and bind9 tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Can [bind](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bind) and [bind9](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/bind9) tags be merged?

Comment: That's assuming every BIND question is about BIND9. What about the other versions of BIND?

Comment: I do not have any data at hand, but IMHO when someone asks about BIND its going to be about BIND9 and not about 4 or 8 or even 10.

Comment: There are still plenty of BIND 8 installation in use and I certainly recall seeing question about that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think having a version tag for every version of every piece of software is necessary. In this case tagging things as bind should narrow the field enough, there shouldn't be a need for a v9 tag.

Comment: I think there is a use for some version-numbers in tags. f.e. the Ubuntu/Windows ones... (http://i.imgur.com/xYCj8.png)

Comment: I agree there are some uses, but is it necessary for bind? At the very least it should be bind-9 to match the format that you just showed for Ubuntu tags. Also, I think the fact that there are so many Ubuntu tags shows that lots of those questions should be on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com and this site should be for more general server oriented questions that might apply to any version of Ubuntu.